Issue with Import intellisense from a custom package
I am trying to setup a custom component library package with Vite, Typescript, and React. The package itself is working fine. However, when I try to type out the import for the package (in a consumer application), the intellisense does not work and I have to fully type out the path. I'm guessing this probably will also affect other intellisense but I have not gotten there yet.
Here's the repo: https://github.com/chingu-x/chingu-dashboard-components
